# How do I scroll down the child popup scrollbar using the robot framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, robotframework, automation-testing

I have to scroll down the child popup scroll bar up to the bottom of the popup using the robot framework. Can you please help with it? Thanks in advance.

I have the below code as an example, but it is not working.

```
Get Product Price
    ${Value1}=    Get WebElement     ${SubTotal}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${Value1}    timeout=60s
    Execute JavaScript    window.document.getElementById('${Value1}').scrollIntoView();
    ${Price}=       Get Text        ${SubTotal}
    Log      Price is:- ${Price}
    Log To Console    \nPrice is:- ${Price}
```

${SubTotal} element is under the child window, and it has the bottom of the child window popup, so I have to scroll down to the ${SubTotal}